# Sort Dictionary by Reference? (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, pass-by-reference

I'm attempting to sort a dictionary in Python in ascending key order. I'm trying to do this inside of a function, with the dictionary being supplied as an argument.

I understand that there are mutable and immutable datatypes in Python, and I understand that a dictionary is supposed to be a mutable datatype. That is, I should be able to pass it by-reference when supplying it as a function argument.

Usually, I would use the `dict(sorted(d.items()))` method, however that does not appear to work when supplying a dictionary by reference.

Here's an example:

```
def CreateDict(d):
    d[0] = "a"
    d[4] = "b"
    d[2] = "c"
    d[1] = "d"

def SortDict(d):
    d = dict(sorted(d.items()))

def main():
    d = {}

    print(d)
    CreateDict(d)
    print(d)
    SortDict(d)
    print(d)

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

Where I add some elements into the dictionary `d` in the `CreateDict` function, and I try to sort it in the `SortDict` function. However, the output I get is the following:

```
{}
{0: 'a', 4: 'b', 2: 'c', 1: 'd'}
{0: 'a', 4: 'b', 2: 'c', 1: 'd'}
```

With `d` remaining unsorted even after a call to `SortDict`.

What is the proper way of sorting a Python dictionary when supplied by-reference as a function argument?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as "pass by reference / pass by value" in Python. Thinking in that way will only confuse you..

Comment: Why don't you just return it?

Comment: Although they can be in practice, dicts are _conceptually_ not ordered, if you need to sort your dict you likely want to use a different data strcuture...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the proper way of sorting a Python dictionary when supplied by-reference as a function argument?

I'd say it's to **return** the new dict, and have the caller use the return value.

But, if you insist on modifying the existing dict, here are a few ways:

```
def SortDict(d):
    items = sorted(d.items())
    d.clear()
    d |= items

def SortDict(d):
    for k in sorted(d):
        d[k] = d.pop(k)

def SortDict(d):
    k = sorted(d)
    d |= zip(k, map(d.pop, k))
```